# complexity of the sum of the squares of geometric progression

Tags: time-complexity

I have a question in my data structure course homework and I thought of 2 algorithms to solve this question, one of them is O(n^2) time and the other one is:

T(n) = 3 * n + 1*1 + 2*2 + 4*4 + 8*8 + 16*16 + ... + logn*logn

And I'm not sure which one is better.

I know that the sum of geometric progression from 1 to logn is O(logn) because I can use the geometric series formula for that. But here I have the squares of the geometric progression and I have no idea how to calculate this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rewrite it as:

```
log n * log n + ((log n) / 2) * ((log n) / 2) + ((log n) / 4) * ((log n) / 4) ... + 1
```

if you substitute (for easier understanding) `log^2 n` with `x`, you get:

```
x + x/4 + x/16 + x/64 + ... + 1
```

You can use formula to sum the series, but if you dont have to be formal, then basic logic is enough. Just imagine you have 1/4 of pie and then add 1/16 pie and 1/64 etc., you can clearly see, it will never reach whole piece therefore:

```
x + x/4 + x/16 + x/64 + ... + 1 < 2x
```

Which means its `O(x)`

Changing back the `x` for `log^2 n`:

```
T(n) = O(3*n + log^2 n) = O(n)
```